# DO Indian Passport Holders Require Transit Visa For Flying Through SOUTH AFRICA for Connecting flights by Emirates-Dubai-Mumbai

Tags: transit, indian-citizens, south-africa

I am a Indian expatriate who lives and works in Angola.I will be flying South African Airways from Luanda -> Johannesburg -emirates > Dubai -> Mumbai.

Do I require a South African transit visa while waiting for about 5-6 hours at the airport for a connecting flight to Dubai?

how about the luggage procedure if in case doesnt require transit visa ?

Answer (score 1):

This is what is shown at [http://iatatravelcentre.com](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/IN-India-passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm) but you can check the requirements with your details.

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>
> Passengers transiting through Cape Town (CPT), Durban (DUR),
>   Johannesburg (JNB) or Lanseria (HLA) with a confirmed onward ticket
>   for a flight to a third country. They must stay in the international
>   transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next
>   destination.